# Deploy time error ( java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/internet/AddressException ) in Jboss 7

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jboss7.x

Our project is in Jetty server and work completely then this project is deployed in Jboss 7 server, but there are some errors.

I make war file and copy and past in `E:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments` folder and auto-deploy become start and give this error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/internet/AddressException
```

but in `\WEB-INF\lib` I have mail.jar file ..

So how to remove this error?

Detail Error :

```
    15:34:02,245 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-4) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factor
y.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'log4jInitialization' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocati
on of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/internet/AddressException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) [org.s
pringframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [org.spri
ngframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [org.spring
framework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:
3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [org.springframework.
beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.
1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.
0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563) [org.springfr
amework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:900) [org.springf
ramework.context-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:455) [org.springframework.context-3.1.0.M
1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) [org.springframework.web-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1
]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:215) [org.springframework.web-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [org.springframework.web-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.
1.0.M1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/internet/AddressException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:336) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:123) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:752) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:735) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:615) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:502) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:547) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:415) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer.initLogging(Log4jConfigurer.java:72) [org.springframework.core-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273) [org.springframework.core-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.doInvoke(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:162) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.0
.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:152) [org.springframework.b
eans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479) [or
g.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417) [org.s
pringframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.internet.AddressException from [Module "org.apache.log4j:main" from local module loader @1da817b (r
oots: E:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules)]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
        ... 43 more
```

So please help , how to remove this error ?

Thanks,

kamlesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JBoss AS 7 comes with isolated class-loading, so you should carefully configure your project dependencies. Details are [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7).

In your case I see that Spring refers to Log4j, which is provided by JBossAS: `Module "org.apache.log4j:main"`, and tries to configure it to do something unusual (possibly, tries to make logging go over e-mail). The problem is that mail-api is not accessible to log4j module, so it complains.

Now you have at least 3 solutions:

1. Make Spring just use log4j without trying to configure it. Instead configure log4j at app-server level. See [this](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Logging+Configuration). Ask Spring experts how to do it :)
2. Put log4j.jar in your /WEB-INF/lib and do not expose `Module "org.apache.log4j"` to your webapp.
3. Expose mail-api to log4j module and delete /WEB-INF/lib/mail.jar from you app. You will have to edit `jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules/org/apache/log4j/main/module.xml` to include a dependency on mail-api:

   ```
   <dependencies>
       <module name="org.dom4j" optional="true"/>
       <module name="javax.api"/>
       <module name="javax.mail.api" export="true"/>
   </dependencies>
   ```

Comment: i use this idea - 3.and this error and get other error : 10:33:10,727 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-2) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factoy.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'log4jInitialization' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocat
on of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/net/ssl/internal/ssl/Provider  , so please help me ....

Comment: I forgot to mention that I ordered the approaches by increasing complexity :) Please show the whole stack-trace, like in original question